# Polling system on Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def quickpoll( ctx, question, *options: str):
    if len(options) <= 1:
        await ctx.send('You need more than one option to make a poll!')
        return
    if len(options) > 10:
        await ctx.send('You cannot make a poll for more than 10 things!')
        return


    if len(options) == 2 and options[0] == 'yes' and options[1] == 'no':
        reactions = ['✅', '❌']
    else:
        reactions = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '6⃣', '7⃣', '8⃣', '9⃣', '']

    description = []
    for x, option in enumerate(options):
        description += '\n {} {}'.format(reactions[x], option)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=question, description=''.join(description))
    react_message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    for reaction in reactions[:len(options)]:
        await react_message.edit(react_message, reaction)
    embed.set_footer(text='Poll ID: {}'.format(react_message.id))
    await react_message.edit(embed=embed)
```

I have this piece of code that makes my discord.py bot create a poll. When I trigger the command, it doesn't do anything. No errors, no messages, nothing. I am thinking that some part of my code could be outdated. No the code is not under a class.

Comment: Have you been able to make a command that works at all? If so, try gradually adding stuff to work towards the poll command that you want, until you find the part that causes a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still using the old documentation when running on a more recent version of d.py.

**[Recent docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)**
**[Major changes from v0.16.x -> v1.x](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html)**

The most notable changes in your case would be:

```py
await self.bot.say(... # <- OLD SYNTAX

# await abc.Messageable.send(... <- general usage for NEW SYNTAX
await ctx.send(... # for your case specifically (which you have used at the top)
```

And for editing the message:

```py
await self.bot.edit_message(... # <- OLD SYNTAX

# await Message.edit(... <- general usage for NEW SYNTAX
await react_message.edit(... # for your case specifically
```

And there's also the old syntax you're using for adding reactions, but you can find the documentation for adding reactions here - same concept as above: [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction).

It's important to make sure what version of a library you're using, as it'll prevent you from running into syntactical errors and mishaps like this in the future. From now on, don't refer to the old documentation at all, only the new docs should be used.

---

**References:**

- [`abc.Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send)
- [`Message.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.pinned)

Comment: It seems to answer with the poll I created, but it doesn't add any reactions. I edited the question

Comment: See if you can solve it - look into [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction). **Hint:** You've got the message object that you want to add the reaction to, and it's a similar syntax to how you're editing the message.

Comment: wheni change it as the documentary says, the program couldn't know what add_reaction is

Comment: `await react_message.add_reaction(reaction)` - It's a coroutine, so you need to await it. You can only `add_reaction()` on a message object, which you have stored in `react_message`. And the coroutine takes **one** parameter, which is the emoji - you have it stored as `reaction`.